# Charge distribution of two infinite wires with constant line charges using Dirac Delta function

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dirac-delta-distributions

In a physics exercise, I need to represent two infinite wires in the y-z-Plane with constant line charges $\pm \lambda $, as a charge distribution $\rho(\vec{r})$, using the Dirac-Delta-function. I added an image which shows the chosen coordinate system for this problem.
[image: The wires are located in the y-z-Plane and each have a distance of a to the z axis]
My guess was $$\rho(\vec{r}) = \lambda \delta(x)[\delta(y+a)-\delta(y-a)]$$

However, in the question it also says "Clue: To determine the constant of proportionality, you can consider a finite piece of the wire with length $L$". I'm not sure where a constant of proportionality pops up, since $\lambda$ is given in the problem. Anyone know where this constant is supposed to come from and what would be the correct solution for $\rho$?

Comment: I don't know, your solution looks fine to me...

Answer (score -1):

You must divide by L so the triple integral gives + $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$ (using my phone).

Comment: Remember: $Q = \iiint_V f(r) d V$, with Q total charge, $V$ charge volume and $f$ the distribution. In your case the wire is finite, but the dimension along $z$ is so large compared to $x$ and $y$ that you can consider the wire is infinite along $z$.

Comment: *You must divide by L.* Dividing by $L$ would give a result that did not have the right dimensions for $\rho$.

Comment: The triple integral of a volume charge density must give a charge, not a linear charge density.

Comment: My bad, stupid problem by thé way... so the answer is $\lambda/L$

Comment: Give me my point